# How to treat the return value of jQuery functions that return a bunch of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to can I treat the return value of jQuery functions that would return a bunch of DOM elements. E.g. I'm using the `.nextAll()` function, that returns a bunch of elements, does it? Can I store the return value in a JS array? Sooner or later I want to iterate through those elements. I know there's the jQuery `.each()` function that would help me out here. Nevertheless, for training and understanding issues I first want to do it step by step.

I'm pretty sure, this basic question is answered somewhere, but I searched for an answer and did not find anything useful for me. Maybe I didn't find the right words. So please be kind.

Comment: Any jQuery collection can be returned to a variable as easy as `var collection = $(element).nextAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` functions typically returns a bunch of DOM elements, it masquerades as an array.

If you run something like:

```
 $('p').css('background-color', 'red');
```

`jQuery` will build an array of all `p` elements, and then applies the `css()` function to each of them.

If you want a single DOM item, use `get` with an index:

```
  $( "li" ).get( 0 )
```

So, `.nextAll()` also typically returns a number of elements, so it is behaving just like `jQuery` typically does.

`each()` is a handy-dandy function that operates on arrays, so it will of course operate just fine on `jQuery` objects:

```
$('li + li').nextAll().each(function(i){
     //glorious code
});
```

You could also do this:

```
var nexts = $('li + li').nextAll();
$.each(nexts, function(i){
     //Glorious code!!
});
```

Hope that makes things clearer!

Comment: `.each` is a method on the jQuery prototype - `$.fn` - meaning you can do `nexts.each(function(i,el) {...})`

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign it to a variable:

```
var $els =  $(selector).nextAll();
```

This way, `$els` will be a jQuery wrapper (array-like object) of the elements.

If you want to have an array of the elements instead, you can use

```
var arr = [].slice.call($els);
```

Comment: can I also assign it to a JS variable?

Comment: That is a js variable... What do you mean?

Comment: I always thought, using the $-sign, I declare a jQuery-object. Maybe I have to revise the basics again.

Comment: @user3005306 `$` is a function which created jQuery objects. But you can make variables with `$` at the beginning of the name. I use it for varibles that contain jQuery objects, to avoid confusion with `HTMLCollection` objects.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation of `.nextall()` says, it returns [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)

> A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM)
>   elements that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a
>   document. Since jQuery methods often use CSS selectors to match
>   elements from a document, the set of elements in a jQuery object is
>   often called a set of "matched elements" or "selected elements".
>
> The jQuery object itself **behaves much like an array**; it has a length
>   property and the elements in the object can be accessed by their
>   numeric indices [0] to [length-1]. Note that a jQuery object **is not
>   actually a Javascript Array object**, so it does not have all the
>   methods of a true Array object such as join().